# Regex for specific syntax

Tags: regex, syntax

For every installed package/application we (our company) create a registry key with a specific syntax.
Examples:

- G_Greenshot_Greenshot_1.2.10.6
- N_Notepad++_Notepad++_7.5.9
- V_VideoLAN_VLCMediaPlayer_3.0.7.1

So basically its [First letter of publisher]_[Publisher]_[Product]_[Productversion]

Now I need a regular expression which finds/selects the registry keys with this specific syntax. Publisher, product and productversion can contain any sign (see example Notepad) except "_" (without the quotes). So the "_" is the delimiter.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your language/tool different syntax restrictions would apply. One example for matching:

```
/\b([A-Z])_\1[^_\s]+_[^_\s]+_\S+/g
```

If you want to capture all parts for further use:

```
/\b([A-Z])_(\1[^_\s]+)_([^_\s]+)_(\S+)/g
```